# Behavior of `super`

Tags: ruby

I have this code:

```
class B
  def self.definer(name, *args, &block)
    define_method(name) { self.instance_exec(*args, &block) }
  end
end
```

and when I try to use it, I get this error:

```
B.definer(:tst) { super }
# => :tst
B.new.tst
# => TypeError: self has wrong type to call super in this context: B (expected #<Class:#<Object:0x007fd3008123f8>>)
```

I understand that `super` has a special meaning, and works little different from calling a method. Can someone explain why and what is happening? It would also be great if someone suggests a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the same error message as you did, but get an error anyway. `super`  must be used within a method definition. But you are not using it in a method definition. That raises an error.

Regarding the solution, I cannot give you one since it is not clear at all what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to define method my own way, I mean do same as define_method, but do some extra work before actual method definition and also before method body call.

And about `super` must be used within method definition, it's not actually true, `define_method` is an example, you can use `super` in it's block and it will work fine.

May be the correct question will be how can I implement `define_method` in pure ruby, without c code, or is it even possible?

Comment: I think the problem is calling super in an `instance_exec`, which changes `self` and the context of the execution such that the method to `super` is lost. `self has wrong type to call super in this context`.  I think there's probably no way to call super in a block passed to instance_exec.

Comment: yes seems like the only way to call `super` outside of method definition is by converting the block to method with something like `rb_add_method` from ruby internals

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't want instance_exec there.

If you didn't have the *args involved, I'd say you just wanted this:

```
def self.definer(name, &block)
  define_method(name, &block) 
end
```

But then your new `definer` method would do the exact same thing that `define_method` does in the first place, so there's be no reason to create it, instead of just using `define_method` in the first place.

What are you actually trying to do? Explain what you want to do, and maybe someone can help you.

But I think the `instance_exec` in your existing implementation isn't what you want -- it is immediately executing the block upon `definer` call, when calling `define_method` -- I think you want the block executed when the method you are defining is being called instead?  But I'm not really sure, it depends on what you're trying to do, which is unclear. `super` doesn't really make any sense within an `instance_exec` -- super to *what* method did you think you'd be calling?

Comment: Example here is reduced, actual usage you can find here https://github.com/jdantonio/functional-ruby/blob/master/lib/functional/pattern_matching.rb#L134. About what method `super` should call, I think current method, it is executed in, I mean when you sending block to the `define_method` super work there, so ruby have some way to specify context of block execution, so all I want is do exactly same, evaluate my code in the context of some method.